# Getting a Function from a Matrix

Tags: matrices, geometry, trigonometry

Given this matrix which I derived from multiplying a rotate and scale matrix by a translate matrix, I'm attempting to write two functions, $x_1$ and $y_1$, to allow me to plug in values that will scale a triangle twice, rotate it $90$ degrees, and translate it to $(7,8)$.

$$
M =
\left[    
\begin{matrix}
S_x (\cos a)  &  (S_y)(\sin a) &  0 \\
S_x(-\sin a)  &  (S_y)(\cos a) &  0 \\
\Delta x      &  \Delta y      &  1
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

$S_x$ = scale in x,
$S_y$ = scale in y,
$\Delta x$ = translation in x,
$\Delta y$ = translation in y,
$a = \alpha$.

I'm just not sure where to begin on this one, so any and all help is much appreciated. Oh, and my professor mentioned that this will be one of the only times we will have to do this so I'm guessing *OpenGL* has some shortcuts for this... that I'm sadly not allowed to use. The two functions I'm looking for are 
$$
x_1 = f(x,y, \sin a, \cos a, \Delta x, \Delta y, S_x, S_y)
$$
and
$$ 
y_1 = g(x,y, \sin a, \cos a, \Delta x, \Delta y, S_x, S_y)
$$
Thanks for your time!

Comment: What kind of vectors do you need, column or row vectors? Your translation is correct for row vectors, your scaling factors are correct for column vectors. One department has to be changed, if I am not wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the position of the translation elements I take you use row vectors.

So by applying the matrix to a row vector by doing the matrix multiplication you get
\begin{align}
u M &= 
(x, y, 1)
\left[    
\begin{matrix}
S_x (\cos a)  &  (S_x)(\sin a) &  0 \\
S_y(-\sin a)  &  (S_y)(\cos a) &  0 \\
\Delta x      &  \Delta y      &  1
\end{matrix}
\right] 
\\
&=
(x S_x \cos(a) - y S_y \sin(a) + \Delta x,
 x S_x \sin(a) + y S_y \cos(a) + \Delta y,
1)
\\
&= (x', y', 1) \\
&= u'
\end{align}
for the transformation from $u=(x,y,1)$ to $u'=(x',y',1)$.

Note: I changed the scaling factors in the matrix.

Here is a visualization:

[image: graph]

(Large version [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uM6rp.png))

Example calculation via the interactive Ruby shell (irb):

```
    irb> $sx = 2.0
=> 2.0
irb> $sy = 2.0
    => 2.0
    irb> $a = Math::PI/2.0
=> 1.5707963267948966
irb> $dx = 7
    => 7
    irb> $dy = 8
=> 8
irb> def f(x,y)
irb> return x*$sx*Math::cos($a) - y*$sy*Math::sin($a) + $dx
    irb> end
    => nil
    irb> def g(x,y)
    irb> return x*$sx*Math::sin($a) + y*$sy*Math::cos($a) + $dy
    irb> end
    => nil
    irb> def h(x,y)
    irb> return [f(x,y),g(x,y)]
    irb> end
    => nil
    irb> h(3,0)
    => [7.0, 14.0]
```

Comment: are the commas in your answer simply just seperating the figures and are still multiplying? Also, do you multiply the matrix by a 1x3 or a 3x1?

Comment: The commas separate the components of the row vectors. You use homogenous coordinates, thus start with a row vector $u = (x, y, 1) $, for the point at $(x,y)$. The result of the matrix multiplication is another row vector. $u' = u M$ (note row vectors are multiplied from the left side of the matrix $M$). If you want to use column vectors, you need to transpose the equations above. A row vector can be interpreted as a matrix with one row and $n$ columns, thus here a $1\times 3$ matrix.

Comment: I tried using the formula to transform a triangle with the points (3,0), (0,5), and (-3,0) to do the following... Rotate 90%, Scale by 2, and translate to (7,8) and I didnt get the right answer, any ideas where I could have went wrong? I got (2,8), (-3,13), and (10,8) in order.

Comment: I get $(7,14)$, $(-3,8)$ and $(7,2)$. What was the supposed result?

Comment: make that (4,8), (-3,13) and (10,8) in order. Rechecked all my math, still not sure

Comment: What you got is exactly right, I'm just not sure where I'm going wrong here. Cos 90 = 0 and sin 90 = 1 correct? Could you show your math for 1 point? I think i'd be able to figure out where I'm going wrong then

Comment: Finally figured out what I was doing wrong, Thanks so much man, I owe ya a beer or something.